# JavaFx. Всплывающая подсказка при наведении на ячейку

Tags: java, javafx

В приложении выводится определенная информация в TableView. Размер текста в некоторых полях довольно большой, и виден не весь текст.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при наведении на конкретную ячейку появлялась всплывающая подсказка с содержимым строки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class Controller{

    @FXML
    TableView<DecisionMessageWrapper> tvNewMessages;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<DecisionMessageWrapper,Boolean> tcAdded;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<DecisionMessageWrapper,Number> tcNewId;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<DecisionMessageWrapper,String> tcNewName;

    public initData (ObservableList<DecisionMessageWrapper newMessages){

        if (newMessages != null) {
             this.newMessages = newMessages;
             tcAdded.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().decisionProperty());
                    tcAdded.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(tcAdded));
             tcAdded.setEditable(true);
             tcNewId.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().getMessage().idProperty());
             tcNewName.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().getMessage().nameProperty());
             tvNewMessages.setItems(newMessages);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы легко передавать такое же поведение другим ячейкам без необходимости дублировать код, создаем свою `CellFactory`:

```
public class ToolTipCellFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell <S, T>>{
        @Override
        public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> param) {
            return new TableCell<S, T>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    //Здесь необходимо установить текст ячейки
                    //И заодно текст всплывающей подсказки
                    if (item==null){
                        setTooltip(null);
                        setText(null);
                    }else {
                        setTooltip(new Tooltip(item.toString()));
                        setText(item.toString());
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

После не забываем зарегистрировать `CellFactory`:

```
tcNewName.setCellFactory(new ToolTipCellFactory<>());
```